# Break three words in three lines when viewport gets too small

Tags: html, css

Is there a native or good browser supported way to wrap ALL words in once when the smaller getting viewport triggers for the first time a word break ?

Example:

> 07/2015 to 01/2016

is lets say three words. As standard it will break when the viewport gets smaller in the first event to:

> 07/2015 to
>   01/2016

and in the second event to:

> 07/2015
>   to
>   01/2016

I tried around with white-space and invisible html characters but no success. It should look like on the second event, the first events example should never happen.

I forget to to write that i use it in a flexbox ( display: flex;)

Comment: add width in different viewport.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.custDate{display:inline;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.custDate{display:inline;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
 .custDate{display:table-caption;}
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution, but it only works as long as the longest "word" isn't longer than two subsequent words in the rest of the phrase. still nice - upvote

Comment: addition to my previous comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jymbGe The difference between the two divs is only one space ("eight nine")

Answer (score 0):

pls use this in media queries

**.className{display:table-caption;}**

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/zgKbg/`
```

Comment: It's inside a complex flexbox "table" and actually  everything works without media queries in all viewports. It is because i wanted to create it as common usable as possible.